# How to use redux component in App.js React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm doing a simple counter app. It has one label, and a button that you can increment by + 1 (each time it's pushed).

Using `redux`, I want to use the count that I store **(in my Redux Store)** in `App.js` file.  However, I'm getting an error:

> Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider

Using the `useSelector` works in other files, just not `App.js`. Is there a work around?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Dogs from './components/Dogs';
import { Provider, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/configureStore'

export default function App() {
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.count);
{/*useSelector does not work in this file!*/}
  return (
    
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{`ha ${count}`}</Text>
        <Dogs />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Counter.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from "react-native";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { increment } from '../redux/ducks/counter'

const Counter = () => {
    const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.count);
 {/*useSelector works in this file!*/}
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleIncrement = () => {
        dispatch(increment())
    };

    return (
      <div>
        {/* <Text>{` COunt: ${count}`}</Text> */}
        <Button onPress={handleIncrement}>Increment</Button>
      </div>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

export default Counter;
```

redux/configureStore.js

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import counterReducer from './ducks/counter';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    counter: counterReducer
});

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

redux/ducks/counter.js

```
const INCREMENT = 'increment';

export const increment = () => ({
    type: INCREMENT
})

const initialState = {
    count: 0
};

export default ( state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case INCREMENT:
            return{...state, count: state.count + 1}
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please post what you have in ConfigureStore.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error saying, you are using `useSelector` out side of provider. In your app.js you are using `useSelector` before the app renders, so it is not able to find store. So, create a component for functionality which you want to use in app.js like this :

Create a file, call it anything like **CountView.js**, in **CountView.js** use your redux login :
**CountView.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const CountView = () => {
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.count);

  return (
    <Text>{`ha ${count}`}</Text>
  )
}

export default CountView;
```

Now, In your app.js use this component :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Dogs from './components/Dogs';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/configureStore'
import CountView from '../components/CountView'; // import CountView component

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* Use component here */}
        <CountView /> 
        <Dogs />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Keep other things as it is, and now your functionality will works.

Answer (score 2):

`useSelector` will work only if you wrap it inside `Provider`. you can create a wrapper file for `App`.

```
const AppWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}> // Set context
      <App /> // Now App has access to context
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

In `App.js`

```
const App = () => {
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.count); // will Work!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a regular React application, an expo React-Native application is not wrapped using an index.js file. Therefore when we wrap the provider in app.js for a React-Native app, we wrap it in index.js for React application. So the hooks like useSelector or useDispatch run before the provider is initialized. So, I would suggest not using any hooks in the app component, instead, we can create other components in the app.js and use the hooks in a separate component like in the code I have used below.

```
const Root = () => {

const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const fetchToken = async () => {
const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
console.log("Stored Token:  ", token);
if (token) {
  dispatch(setAuthLogin({ isAuthenticated: true, token }));
 }
};

const LoadFonts = async () => {
 await useFonts();
};

useEffect(() => {
 async function prepare() {
  try {
    await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
    await LoadFonts();
    await fetchToken();
  } catch (e) {
     console.warn(e);
  } finally {
     setAppIsReady(true);
  }
}
prepare();
}, []);

const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
 if (appIsReady) {
   await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
 }
}, [appIsReady]);

if (!appIsReady) {
 return null;
}

return (
 <NavigationContainer onReady={onLayoutRootView}>
   <MainNavigation />
 </NavigationContainer>
 );
};

export default function App() {
 return (
 <>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ExpoStatusBar style="auto" />
    <Root />
  </Provider>
 </>
 );
}
```